# How to simplify the result of this integral

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The solution of the following integral:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - Cos[x - x1]], {x, 0, Pi}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

is

```
(1/Sqrt[1 + Cos[x1]])Csc[x1/2] ((Log[Cos[(\[Pi] + x1)/4]] - Log[Sin[(\[Pi] + x1)/4]]) Sin[x1] + (-Log[Cos[x1/4]] + Log[-Sin[x1/4]]) Sqrt[Sin[x1]^2])
```

It can be simplified further using logarithm properties and the definition of the `Tan[(\[Pi] + x1)/4]`. I tried to `FullSimplify`, `TrigReduce` and `FullSimplify` after `TrigExpand` but nothing worked.

How can I simplify it?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?  I get a different result with V11.0.  Substituting `x1->0.4`, I get (different) complex results for both expressions.

Comment: @mikado Version 10 for Windows 64 bits. I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: I don't think the integral converges for real values of `x1`, but will do for complex values.  Perhaps you need to provide assumptions on the sign of the imaginary part of `x1`?

Comment: Often if you know the transformations you want to apply, it is simpler to do so explicitly than to find the perfect combination of simplification functions.

Comment: `Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - Cos[x - x1]], {x, 0, π}, 
 Assumptions -> {π < x1 < 2 π}]`  may give an expression closer to what you want.

Comment: @LouisB That's exactly what I want! Thank you!